# Laravel Websockets

Tags: laravel, websocket, liveserver

I have setup my laravel websockets on localhost it works fine on localhost but when i upload hostinger Hpanel for live calling system  then console shown Websocket failed error.

I want that Websocket fine working as well as localhost.

Comment: Is it possible to have your development environment running on `http` and your production environment system running on `https`?